# How to return a member variable of one class object, as a member variable of another in C++

Tags: c++

how do I make `ben.get_name()` return "Beniah"? Here is my full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Worker;

class Person{
  public:
  Person(int Age, Worker worker){
    age = Age;
    name = worker.get_name();
  }

  string get_name(){
    return name;
  }

  private:
  int age;
  string name;
};


class Worker{
  public:
  Worker(string Level, string Name){
    level = Level;
    name = Name;
  }
  string get_name(){
    return name;
  }

  private:
  string level;
  string name;
};

int main(){

  Worker worker1 = Worker("base", "Beniah");
  Person ben = Person(27, worker1);

  cout << ben.get_name();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare an instance of a class, the class definition must already be known. If it is not, you can only use pointers or references to class instances.

Here you just should define `Worker` before `Person`.

BTW, you should not pass a copy of the Worker object when a ref would be enough, or even better a const ref if you declare the `get_name` method `const` (what it is actually).

You code could become:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::string;

class Worker {
public:
    Worker(string Level, string Name) {
        level = Level;
        name = Name;
    }
    string get_name() const {
        return name;
    }

private:
    string level;
    string name;
};

class Person {
public:
    Person(int Age, const Worker& worker) {
        age = Age;
        name = worker.get_name();
    }

    string get_name() {
        return name;
    }

private:
    int age;
    string name;
};


int main() {

    Worker worker1 = Worker("base", "Beniah");
    Person ben = Person(27, worker1);

    cout << ben.get_name();

    return 0;
}
```

---

Alternatively, or if you have circular dependencies, you can defer the definitions of the methods that would actually use the `Worker` class. Here is a minimal change from your original code that just defers the constructor definition:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Worker;

class Person {
public:
    // Worker is just a forward declaration here
    // just use it in the declaration part
    Person(int Age, Worker worker); /* {
        age = Age;
        name = worker.get_name();
    }*/

    string get_name() {
        return name;
    }

private:
    int age;
    string name;
};


class Worker {
public:
    Worker(string Level, string Name) {
        level = Level;
        name = Name;
    }
    string get_name() {
        return name;
    }

private:
    string level;
    string name;
};

// Worker is now fully defined, we can use it in Person ctor
Person::Person(int Age, Worker worker) {
    age = Age;
    name = worker.get_name();
}

int main() {

    Worker worker1 = Worker("base", "Beniah");
    Person ben = Person(27, worker1);

    cout << ben.get_name();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what about if the worker class was dependent on the Person class for initialization. for example, If the Person class takes a Worker object during initilization and so it could get the age from that person object and store the age as it's own member variable. Would the way you have shown for me to structure my classes change?

Comment: @Nnamdi: Please see my edit...

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those rare cases where it might actually make sense to use inheritance:

```cpp
class Person {
    std:string name;
    int age;
public:
    Person(std::string const &name, int age) 
        : name(name), age(age) 
    {}

    std::string get_name() const { return name; }
    int get_age() const { return age; }

    virtual ~Person() = default;
};

class Worker : public Person {
    std::string level;
public:
    Person(std::string const &name, int age, std::string const &level) 
        : Person(name, age), level(level)
    {}

    std::string get_level() const { return level; }
};

int main() { 
    Worker ben("Beniah", 27, "base");

    std::cout << ben.get_name();
}
```

By using public inheritance, we're asserting that a `Worker` is a `Person`--or more precisely, that in any situation where we want a `Person`, somebody can always substitute a `Worker` instead.

By using inheritance to asser that a `Worker` is a `Person`, we've assured that all the operations we've defined for a `Person` are also defined for a `Worker`, including calling `Person::get_name` on a `Worker` object, even though `get_name` is defined only in `Person`, not directly in `Worker`.

Inheritance definitely has a number of downsides though, so you probably want to examine it carefully before you make any sort of irrevocable decision to use it.

In any case, if you wanted to add a constructor for `Worker` that took a `Person` and a `level`, you could easily do that as well. Or you could (for example) create a static member function in `Worker` named something like `hire` that would take a `Person` and create a `Worker`:

```cpp
class Worker {
/// ...
    static Worker hire(Person p, int level);
};
```

This does have some effects people might not like though, especially on a philosophical level. For example, each time you `hire` a `Person`, you're creating a `Worker` object that includes a `Person`, so you're kind of saying that when you hire somebody, they're a brand new person, copied from the existing `Person`, rather than actually being that existing `Person`. There are times/situations where that may be a problem (and others where it's not).